# Is it possible to get a count of the number of times a Facebook Open Graph action has been connected to an Object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

ie. let's say your Open Graph objects are "recipes" and your action is "cook".  Can you get a global count of how many users have cooked a given recipe from the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you looking for exists in [OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and called aggregations, see [Define Aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/). But there is currently no possibility to get aggregations via [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

There is a feature request for this in [BUG #209141539176726](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/209141539176726) which is tracked in wishlist.

You may consider storing aggregated counts of action publishing in your application.